# Usage of 'quick' as adverb

Tags: phrase-meaning, adverbs, adverbial-phrases

I heard the following dialog in a British English movie:

> Words go round **quick**. All the little tongues go clack, clack, clack.

What does this mean, and why was the word "quick" used instead of "quickly"?

Comment: Which movie, pray tell?

Comment: It is 'Wish you were here'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see **quickly** as the correct adverb; I would correct my children if they said:

> He's running quick.

However **quick** is widely used as an adverb, and in some phrases seems to work better:

> a get rich quick scheme
>
> Do it, and do it real quick

Some dictionaries do include that **quick** may be used as an adverb.

President George W Bush

> We want to get this bridge rebuilt as quick as possible.

[This article has some interesting observations](http://blog.oup.com/2007/08/adverb/)

At to the meaning of the passage. The idea is of information (and suspect in particular malicious gossip) being transmitted very quickly from person to person. The individual tongues working very quickly like components of a machine.

This comes to mind:

> A lie can travel halfway around the world before the truth can get its boots on

Comment: Yep, normal usage in America and, under the influence of Holywood, more and more wide-spread in Britain too.

Comment: Would you correct your children if they said *He's doing it quick?* In other words, I'm interested in how 'Do it quick' is okay for you,   but not 'He's running quick'.

Comment: As A. Toumanstev said: the "quick as adverb" idiom is largely picked-up from Hollywood movies. If "He's doing it quick" was said in the context of someone having recently said "do it real quick" I'd let it go. In isolation I'd correct it. Similarly I see it as fun to use other slang expressions. "We ain't going nowhere today" but I would pick up the ain't and double negatives in other contexts.

Comment: I think I understand  what @A.Toumantsev is saying, but as my answer notes, the flat adverb 'quick' has a long and venerable history. I don't think there's anything "Hollywood" about  it, if that is supposed to mean something along the lines of  "bad usage corrupting language".

Comment: My comment was about "dropping the -ly" in general. Actually, being a non-native speaker I didn't even know of "do it quick", so I've learnt smth new. [Upvoted your answer]  What I had in mind was: "The weather is real good today", or (with John Wayne's voice) "Man, you gotta hit the road now and you gotta do it real fast" :)

Answer (score 5):

**quick** can be both adjective and adverb. In spoken language it may be used instead of **quickly** as an adverb mostly in exclamations or comparatives.

> Come quick, Larry's on TV
>
> Quick! there is a mouse

Answer (score 5):

‘Quick’ (without -ly) *is* an adverb, as well as an adjective. An adverb does not have to end in -ly and often such adverbs that do not are called ‘flat adverbs’ (see [Flat adverbs are flat-out useful](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/)).

‘Quick’ as an adverb has been used since 1300, per the *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED), which includes usages of the flat adverb ‘quick’ from Shakespeare, Milton, Locke, Chesterfield, Dickens, Tennyson, and Sandburg.

*Do it quick*, *Come quick*, and your *Words go round quick* are natural uses of *quick* as an adverb.

However, the OED also says that the use of *quick* as an adverb is

> **usually** considered less formal than *quickly*, and found **chiefly** in informal or colloquial contexts [my emphases].

One might also add *dialectal* to that sentence, as its acceptance and/or usage in formal contexts may depend on the dialect of the speaker.