# Why "think bright" is used with adjective instead of adverb (think brightly)?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, adverbs

I find "think bright" is much more common usage, but why? In my opinion, "Think" is a verb, so it is reasonable to use adverb to describe it.

Examples:
[image]

> THINK BRIGHT!
>
> ## The National University of Science and Technology MISIS

<sup>([Source: MISIS](http://misis.ru/files/-/acfd14286d02bc9f2e16fc0474778926/ENG_Student_WWW_210%D1%85210-%D0%9E%D0%9A.pdf))</sup>

Comment: I've never encountered "Think Bright" in normal speech or written text. Where do you see it? There is a campaign and associated slogan, but we don't always expect good English in such things.

Comment: How about some examples where you found this used.

Comment: @djna I admit it is just a mistake, but there is some examples:
1) google - http://imgur.com/a/2L4tA
2) University brochure http://misis.ru/files/-/acfd14286d02bc9f2e16fc0474778926/ENG_Student_WWW_210%D1%85210-%D0%9E%D0%9A.pdf

Comment: @djna suppose slogan (I didn't specify i'm talking about normal speech), is `think brightly` more correct in this case?

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail - I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *think bright*, *bright* is used as an adverb. This is similar to [think different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_different). Such adverbs--whether standard or not--are called **[flat adverbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94713/usage-of-quick-as-adverb/94719#94719)**, because they lack the *-ly* ending associated with most adverbs. For example, in *I had to think hard about this sentence*, *hard* is a flat adverb.

Comment: So, why do we use flat adverbs? Do we just want talk faster and less formal or `bright` has other meaning compared to `brightly` (and similarly with other flat and non-flat adverbs)?

Comment: Well @jumpjet67 the two adverbs *hard* and *hardly* have different meanings as normally used. I suggest the Daily Writing Tips's [Flat Adverbs Are Flat-Out Useful](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/).

Answer (score 1):

> Some shine bright, but never seem to hang around for long.
>
> It was unnerving how bright they shone and so I tried to look away.
>
> The sun is shining bright in the sky and nobody else is around.

According to OxforddIctionaries.com **bright** can be a noun, an adjective and an adverb, which has a  literary meaning  *brightly* (see the examples).